# Are URLs with &amp; instead of & treated the same by search engines?

Tags: url, seo, ampersand

I'm validating one of my web pages and its throwing up errors as below :

> `&` did not start a character reference. (`&` probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

This is because on my page I am linking to internal webpages which has `&`'s in the URL as below:

```
www.example.com/test.php?param1=1&param2=2
```

My question is that if I change the URLs in the a hrefs to include `&amp;` as below:

```
www.example.com/test.php?param1=1&amp;param2=2
```

Will Google and other search engines treat the 2 URLs above as separate pages or will they treat them both as the one below:

```
www.example.com/test.php?param1=1&param2=2
```

I dont want to loose my search engine rankings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Hi John,  I added the tag of 'SEO' when I created the question and it says 'SEO' in the question title, is this not ok?  I'm not sure why its off topic.

Comment: @user1052096: Many SEO questions are off-topic here. Mainly those that ask for advice or those that ask what search engines support/like/want. As the [tag:seo] tag description says, if your question is not related to a programming problem, you should ask it on [webmasters.se] (but check if it’s on-topic there before).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to assume that search engines would knowingly ignore how HTML works.

Take, for example, this hyperlink:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/test.php?param1=1&amp;param2=2">…</a>
```

The URL is *not* `http://example.com/test.php?param1=1&amp;param2=2`!

It’s just the way how the URL `http://example.com/test.php?param1=1&param2=2` is stored in attributes in an HTML document.

So when a conforming consumer comes across this hyperlink, it never visits `http://example.com/test.php?param1=1&amp;param2=2`.